# Making a list app with a mysql db items won't add

Tags: java, mysql, spring, thymeleaf

Hello today I am trying to make a list app using an html interface to add items to a mysql database. My error is one of the columns in my sql can not be null, but one of my portions to the html should be supplying that info and not making it null.  I am working with Java Spring and Thymeleaf as my frameworks and code as well.

This is the error

```
2016-12-02 12:43:13.386  WARN 6932 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 23502, SQLState: 23502
2016-12-02 12:43:13.386 ERROR 6932 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : NULL not allowed for column "PRIORITY"; SQL statement:
update list_items set contents=?, created_utc=?, is_checked=?, list_id=?, modified_utc=?, priority=? where id=? [23502-192]
2016-12-02 12:43:13.386  INFO 6932 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.h.e.j.b.internal.AbstractBatchImpl     : HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
2016-12-02 12:43:15.685 ERROR 6932 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement] with root cause

org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: NULL not allowed for column "PRIORITY"; SQL statement:
update list_items set contents=?, created_utc=?, is_checked=?, list_id=?, modified_utc=?, priority=? where id=? [23502-192]
```

Here is my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
    xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
    layout:decorator="layouts/basic">
<head>
<title>Getting Started: Serving Web Content</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body layout:fragment="content">
    <h1>Add Item</h1>
    <form method="POST" th:object="${list_items}"
        enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" th:field="*{id}" />
        <input type="hidden" name="utc" th:field="*{createdUtc}" />
        <input type="hidden" name="utc" th:field="*{modifiedUtc}" />
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="contents">Contents</label> <input type="text"
                name="contents" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1"
                placeholder="Contents" th:field="*{contents}" /> <span
                th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('Contents')}" th:errors="*{contents}">Contents
                Error</span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="priority">Priority: </label> <select name="priority">
                <option th:selected="*{priority} == 0" value="0">It can
                    wait</option>
                <option th:selected="*{priority} == 1" value="1">Need it
                    soon</option>
                <option th:selected="*{priority} == 2" value="2">Grab it
                    now</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <!--
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox"> Check me out
    </label>
  </div>
  -->
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Add</button>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is part of my controller.

```
// GetMapping and PostMapping for editing items in lists.
    @GetMapping("/ListsofLists/{id}/add")
    public String listItemAdd(Model model, @PathVariable(name = "id") int id) {
        model.addAttribute("id", id);
        ListItem u = listItemRepo.findOne(id);
        model.addAttribute("list_items", u);
        return "list_item_add";
    }

    @PostMapping("/ListsofLists/{id}/add")
    public String listItemSave(@ModelAttribute @Valid ListItem listItem, BindingResult result, Model model) {
        listItemRepo.save(listItem);
        return "redirect:/ListsofLists/{id}";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you change the priority drop down to look like this:

```
<select th:field="*{priority}">
    <option value="0">It can wait</option>
    <option value="1">Need it soon</option>
    <option value="2">Grab it now</option>
</select>
```

Have you verified that any of the data is bound to your object? You might need `@ModelAttribute("list_items")` as well.

Comment: I just tried the new look for the <select> it did not seem to change my error. as for the data that should be bound with my listItem in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this does not continue to be a recurring thing, as I do appreciate the help I get. My Priority I forgot to mention in the data is an enum that converts certain Strings into Integers. I had to set the Values in the HTML as those Strings. That is why i was getting a Null error thanks to the fact that my values were incorrect.

```
<select
                th:field="*{priority}">
                <option value="Itcanwait">It can wait</option>
                <option value="Needitsoon">Need it soon</option>
                <option value="Grabitnow">Grab it now</option>
            </select>
```

is what I changed it to for those who look upon this in the future.